# Eclipse 'Project Explorer View' doesn't show Errors - Stack Overflow

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

In the "Project Explorer" view of a maven project, instead of showing errors (compilation) in the project itself (red blade), they appear at the level of the folder src .. etc ... which is extremely uncomfortable since priori it seems that all projects compile ...

On the other hand, "Package Explorer" comes out both at the Project level and at the folder level

Version of Eclipse: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers Version: Photon Release (4.8.0)[image] .

(Update !!! )Note : **This happens again in this Eclipse Version: 2022-03-RC1 (4.23.0)**

**(Update !!! )Note : **This has been fixed at this Eclipse Version: 2022-06-M1 ((4.24.0 M1)****

Comment: I did not follow, what is the issue or the intended behavior?

Comment: The intended behavior is to show a red "x"  into the project level, not just inside this into the package src...

Comment: any screen shot will help to understand in depth. Have you tried to `update maven` to  your projects or `maven clean` ?

Comment: Yes Ros, but it seems that is only one thing that happens in "Project Explorer View" ... in Package vie shows fine

Comment: Attached screen

Answer (score 0):

- try to Check your source directory is listed in source folder of project

  Right-click your project > Build Path > Configure Build Path > Source.
- If you are using multiple projects (as dependencies)

  Project->Clean
- [image]

Check "Build Automatically" is enabled or not.

- project > Build Automatically
  [image]

you can try and hope it will help you a lot

Comment: Nothing. Checked that source directoy is listed. Build and cleaned also. The error is always shown at folder level , not project level as it is at Package level

Comment: Right click on maven project in eclipse > Maven > Update project.

It solved my problem.

If the problem still persists, look in the Problems tab (Window Menu > show view > Problems) and it should give the description of the error.

try it

Comment: Yes the problem is shown at "Problems View" , but never at project leven into de "Project View"....

Comment: Its just a compiling error... but whatever the error, the only just thing i want its to be shown as project level ))

Comment: Right-Click Project --> Build Path --> Configure Build Path; unselect the SRC, save, select again

try it

Comment: Thank u, but finally i have updated to last version of Eclipse and now works fine.  Thank you

Comment: I  answer myself 3 years after ....because this issue happens again with 2022-03-RC1 (4.23.0) ( march of 2022)